# Symfony request stays empty while sending file from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, symfony

I'm trying to send a file using React.js and the dropzone package.
I can send the file but the request in my php controller doesn't contain the file.

Here is the code:

Javascript:

```
handleDrop = files => {
  // const uploaders = files.map(file => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", files[0], 'picture');

      return axios.post("http://localhost:8000/upload", formData, {
          headers: {
              'accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
          }})
          .then(response => {
              const data = response.data;
              console.log(data);
          })
  // })
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavigationBar>
                displaySearchFields={'none'}
            </NavigationBar>
            <Dropzone onDrop={this.handleDrop}>
                <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
            </Dropzone>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Php:

```
/**
 * @Route("/upload", methods={"POST", "OPTIONS"}, name="upload")
 */
public function uploadImageToDatabase(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->files->get("file");

    $this->saveImage($data);

    return new JsonResponse($request);
}

public function saveImage($image){
    $fp = fopen("D:\Temp\imageToEncode.png", "w");
    fwrite($fp, $image);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm quite sure that `FormData` take a `<form>` selector as parameter

Comment: I didn't see people do that on the posts that I found though, but it seems logical anyway :D how should I do it you think?

Comment: You won't need `formData.append` btw

Comment: How do you mean? Sorry New at javascript

Comment: Doing `const formData=new FormData(document.getElementById(MyFormId))` will include every inputs in the form. Thus you don't need to append any data

Comment: That still doesn't work i'm afraid